# Cake PHP: Converting from Sql Server to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, cakephp

I'm testing a conversion of our site's database from Sql Server to MySQL on a Cake PHP 1.2 site, and I've run into an error in how cake is storing my model's info now. When creating my "emp" (employee, not my naming scheme) model I get the following error now:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index:  id [CORE\app\models\emp.php, line 83]
```

Here is the code generating the SQL and that should be populating the model's data

```
    function findInfo($ecode = false) {
    /*The SQL statement*/
    $sql = "Select id as 'Emp__id', code as 'Emp__code',
                        first_name as 'Emp__first_name', last_name as 'Emp__last_name',
                        created as 'Emp__created', modified as 'Emp__modified',
                        password as 'Emp__password', active as 'Emp__active',
                        hidden_flag as 'Emp__hidden_flag'
                        from rs_emp as Emp
                        where code Like '$ecode' limit 1";
    $employee = $this->query($sql);
    $employee = $employee[0];
    /*the below lines return the undefined index error
    $employee['Permission'] = $this->findPermissions($employee['Emp']['id']);
    $employee['Plant'] = $this->findPlants($employee['Emp']['id']);
    return $employee;
}
```

The error means that it's not finding $employee['Emp']['id'], I assumed the `Select id as 'Emp__id'` statements took care of that, as the old code worked. Is this something that can be corrected?

I assume this would NOT be a problem if custom queries were removed and instead Cake's query system were used, correct? The only reason I haven't started replacing them myself is I'm not sure how and I didn't build the system, if there's a super quick fix to the above sql statement I'll do that, I'm currently testing to see how easy it would be to move us to MySQL, but long term I do plan to move over to Cake's query model.

Comment: What is the query returning? Can you do a `print_r($employee)`;

Comment: You're selecting the field `id` and call it `Emp__id`, so naturally there's no `id` key in the array. Am I missing something or shouldn't it be the other way around (`SELECT Emp__id AS id)`?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that Webbiedave, I forget I can do that with arrays; it wasn't storing the values as expected.

Comment: Juhana you were actually right; I don't know why it was pulling them as Emp_id, but the as statement is totally unnecessary...at least now that I'm using mysql. I don't know why it had it before, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had made the mistake of assuming the `Select id as 'Emp__id'` method was correct; it wasn't. Simply removing the `as` statements solved this problem, the array now reads the properly named indexes. I just don't know why the as statements were ever included.